# Solving system of equations with fraction

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

I am having difficulties solving the following system :

$u \neq t$ and $(t, u) \in \mathbf{R} - \{-1, 1\}$

$\frac{t}{t^2-1}-\frac{u}{u^2-1}=0$

$\:\frac{t^2}{t-1}-\frac{u^2}{u-1}=0$

I tried expanding everything, but I still can't achieve anything

$\frac{tu^2-t-ut^2+u}{\left(t^2-1\right)\left(u^2-1\right)}$

$\frac{t^2u-t^2-u^2t+u^2}{\left(t-1\right)\left(u-1\right)}$

also tried the hint below, ending up finding one equation with the two variables $t(t+1) = u(u+1)$ ... and $u \neq t$

Any idea ?

Comment: It is a quadratic equation in $t$, which you can solve.

Comment: @nginx9101 Show please how you made this expanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{cases}
    \frac{t}{t^2-1}-\frac{u}{u^2-1}=0 \\
    \frac{t^2}{t-1}-\frac{u^2}{u-1}=0 \\
\end{cases} 
\begin{array}{c}
    \overset{\times(t^2-1)(u^2-1)\ne0}{\longrightarrow} \\
    \overset{\times(t-1)(u-1)\ne0}{\longrightarrow}\\
\end{array}
\begin{cases}
    t(u^2-1)-u(t^2-1)=0 \\
    t^2(u-1)-u^2(t-1)=0 \\
\end{cases} 
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
    tu^2-t-ut^2+u=0 \\
    t^2u-t^2-u^2t+u^2=0 \\
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
    tu(u-t)+u-t=0 \\
    tu(t-u)-(t-u)(t+u)=0 \\
\end{cases} 
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
    (u-t)(tu+1)=0 
    \begin{cases}
        u-t=0 \Rightarrow u=t \text{ incorrect} \\
        tu+1=0 \Rightarrow tu=-1 \\
    \end{cases}\\
    (t-u)(tu-(t+u))=0
    \begin{cases}
        t-u=0 \Rightarrow u=t \text{ incorrect} \\
        tu-(t+u)=0 \Rightarrow tu=t+u \\
    \end{cases} 
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
    tu=-1 \\
    t+u=tu \\
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
    tu=-1 \\
    t+u=-1 \\
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
u^2+u-1=0
\Rightarrow
\text{...}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{t^2}{t-1}}{\dfrac t{t^2-1}}=?$$

$$\implies t(t+1)=u(u+1)$$

But $u\ne t$

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do?.. Details please?

Comment: @nginx9101, replace the values of the numerator and denominator

Comment: well yes, but your reasoning isn't complete yet. What to do after ? I end up having 2 variables which I can't solve